# How can I kill all current procs/users attached to my MS ACCESS DB?

Tags: ms-access

MS Office 365 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

Hi:
I need to be able to kill all current users who are attached to my MSACCESS DB.
I cannot make a metadata change to my DB which is shared with other users because it reports that another user is attached to the DB.  This DB is on a shared disk which the users can mount and use. The LACCDB file has a single line in it that points right to a windows server where I run a "task scheduler" job 1x/wk. That appears to be the culprit and I'm trying to shut it down.

I go to the windows server, go into task scheduler, see the task and "end all instances of this task".  No change in the LACCDB, the DB is still locked.  I go back and "disable" the task.  Still no change in the LACCDB.

I ran "tasklist" on the server and saw MSACCESS. I tried "taskkill /F /PID " but apparently I don't have permission to do that.  So I opened Access, attached to the DB and gracefully "closed" the DB (as opposed to simply killing MSACCESS by clicking the "x").  Then, with no other way to exit MSACCESS, I clicked the "x" to get out.  Still no change in LACCDB.

At the risk of corrupting the DB, I tried to change the permissions of the LACCDB and just delete it.  No luck, it won't let me, some other app has it opened.

I am the ADMIN of this DB.  Is there a way I can safely kill all current attachments to my DB, even if that means losing whatever changes those attached users may have in flight ?

Thanks in Advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that the file is not actually open. To do this you need to be on fileserver that is hosting the share.

Use this command to list open files:

```
net file
```

If it is open then you need to get the connection ID. Then use the ID in this command:

```
net file <ID> /close
```

Once the file is no longer locked by the OS you can delete the .LACCDB

Open the DB file and use the `Compact and Repair` option to save it.

You can now get exclusive access to the DB.

SEE ALSO: [How to see who is using my Access database over the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899930/how-to-see-who-is-using-my-access-database-over-the-network)

Comment: Thanks You HackSlash for the response.  Unfortunately, they're not going to let me log into the fileserver.  Even if they did, they'll never let me kill network connections.  I tried and I simply don't have access.  What's really missing here is the ability for someone designated as a DBA to simply boot users.  But I expect that an ACCESS DB, and the .LACCDB for that matter,  is really nothing more than a file that gets managed in windows in that way, not a true DB with true DBA admin features.

Comment: Correct. An Access DB is just a file. The good news is that you can use SQL as the back-end for your Access DB. Install the free SQL-Express and then follow a guide for exporting from Access to SQL. Then link the new SQL tables in your front end. Ba-boom. Then you can manage the back end like a real DBA.